# Can You Change Buttons color onfocuse In Nativescript/Angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue

Can You Change Buttons color onfocused like yout do in TextField In Nativescript/Angular..
It works in TextField but not in BUTTON
Does someone knows some other solution, im trying to build a tvapp i need to change the color when is focused in Button or Label

##### HTML File

```
<Page loaded="onPageLoaded($event)">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button  text="My Button 2"  class="my_button_2" >  </Button>
        <TextField class="input-field"> </TextField>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

###### CSS File

```
.my_button_2:focus{
    background:olive;
    border-color: red;
    border: 2;
    border-width: 2;
}

.my_button_2:active{
    background:olive;
    border-color: red;
    border: 2;
    border-width: 2;
}


.input-field:focus {
border-bottom-color: red;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution in Android onloaded event

##### HTML

```
<Button #myButton1 text="My Button 1" (tap)="OnTapButton_1($event)" (loaded)="onButtonLoaded_1($event)" class="button_style"></Button>
```

##### Component.ts File

```
public onButtonLoaded_1(args) {
    let btn = args.object as Button;
    let androidButton = btn.android;

    androidButton.setOnFocusChangeListener(new android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener({
      onFocusChange:(view, hasFocus) => {
          if(hasFocus === true){
            btn.addPseudoClass("focus")
          }
          else {
            btn.deletePseudoClass("focus")

          }
        }
      }))
}
```

##### CSS

```
.button_style {
    android-elevation: 0;
    android-dynamic-elevation-offset: 0;
    background: rgba(190, 138, 17, 0.315);
    border-width: 0.3;
    border-color: rgba(190, 138, 17, 0.671);

}

.button_style:focus{
    android-elevation: 0;
    android-dynamic-elevation-offset: 0;
    background: rgba(190, 138, 17, 0.856);
    border-width: 0.3;
    border-color: rgba(116, 84, 11, 0.856);
}
```

##### Disbaling in it

```
androidButton.setOnFocusChangeListener(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the nativescript's [UI & Styling docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui-and-styling.html#pseudo-selector), nativescript currently supports only the `:highlighed` pseudo selector on Button.

You should use it like this:

```
.my_button_2:highlighted {
    background:olive;
    border-color: red;
    border: 2;
    border-width: 2;
}
```

Note: by default on Android, the Button element is not focusable. So if you want to enable focus on an Android Button element, you need to first add modifications to its native component (android.widget.Button) using the following:

Add a 'loaded' eventlistener:

```
<Button (loaded)="onButtonLoaded($event)" text="My Button 2"  class="my_button_2"></Button>
```

Then, when the element is loaded, enable focus:

```
import { Button } from "@nativescript/core";

export class AppComponent {
    onButtonLoaded(event: TapGestureEventData) {
        const btn = event.object as Button;

        const androidButton = btn.android;
        androidButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); // make Button focusable
    }
}
```

This makes the Button focusable, and you can focus on it manually like so:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Button } from "@nativescript/core";

export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild("btn") btn: ElementRef<Button>;

    focusBtn() {
        const isFocused = this.btn.nativeElement.focus();
        console.log(`did focus? ${isFocused}`);
    }
}
```

***Note:** You still can't use the `button:focus` css pseudo-selector due to the framework limitation to `:highlighted` as described above.*

However, to solve your case, as a work around if your scenario is to set the focus manually, then you can use the following to achieve a focus-similar behavior (works on both Android and iOS):

CSS:

```
.focus {
    background:yellow;
    border-color: red;
    border: 2;
    border-width: 2;
}
```

.html template:

```
<Button (loaded)="onButtonLoaded($event)" text="My Button 2"  class="my_button_2" [ngClass]="{ 'focus': buttonIsFocused }"></Button>
```

.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
    buttonIsFocused = false;

    focusOnButton() {
        // call this when you wish to add focus styling to the button
        this.buttonIsFocused = true;
    }

    defocusButton() {
        // call this when you wish to remove the focus styling
        this.buttonIsFocused = false;
    }
}
```

Check [this](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui-and-styling.html#supported-selectors) to read more about nativescript styling.
Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/25027) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/17251?answerId=57956022#57956022) to read more about the native iOS focusing.

Comment: The Problem is im not  trying to get focus in touch,Im bulind an TV APP i need to navigate with DPAD so it needs to get focus automatically before i touch.By the way i solved it in android for ios i have sitll no idea im going to post the solution

Comment: Got it. Check my third link at the end, It is about the Focus system on tvOS. Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the same solution for android but as Angular Directive

######## HTML #####################

```
<Button #myButton1 text="My Button 1" class="button_style" focusable (focusChange)="onFocusChange($event)"></Button>
```

##### Directive.ts File

```
import {Directive, ElementRef,EventEmitter,Output} from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
    selector: '[focusable]'
  })
  export class FocusableDirective {
    @Output('focusChange') focusChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
    constructor(private el: ElementRef<any>) {
      el.nativeElement.once('loaded', () => {
        el.nativeElement.android.setOnFocusChangeListener(new android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener({
          onFocusChange: (view, hasFocus) => {
              this.focusChange.emit(hasFocus);
             }
         }));
        })
      }
  }
```

##### Component.ts File

```
  public onFocusChange(hasFocus){
    const mybtn = <Label>this.myButton.nativeElement
    if(hasFocus === true){
      mybtn.addPseudoClass("focus")
    }
    else {
      mybtn.deletePseudoClass("focus")

    }
  };
```

######## CSS #############

```
.button_style {
    android-elevation: 0;
    android-dynamic-elevation-offset: 0;
    background: rgba(190, 138, 17, 0.315);
    border-width: 0.3;
    border-color: rgba(190, 138, 17, 0.671);

}

.button_style:focus{
    android-elevation: 0;
    android-dynamic-elevation-offset: 0;
    background: rgba(190, 138, 17, 0.856);
    border-width: 0.3;
    border-color: rgba(116, 84, 11, 0.856);
}
```